# callback a looped result from python with ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, python

Am trying to callback a looped result from python with ajax jquery as shown below but instead only one result is shown

```
for cont in summary_conatiner:
  head_container = cont.find("b")
  head = head_container.text
  info_container = cont.find("span", { "class": "phrase" })
  info = info_container.text
  return jsonify({'result': head + ' ' +  info + '\n'})
```

```js
$.ajax({
  data: { search : sea },
  url: '/process',
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(response) {
    $('#get_search').html(response.result);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `return` statement interrupts the loop when it reached on the first iteration, so you get only one result in callback.

You should form result list and then return it:

```
results =[]
for cont in summary_conatiner:
    head_container = cont.find("b")
    head = head_container.text
    info_container = cont.find("span", { "class": "phrase" })
    info = info_container.text
    results.append(head + ' ' +  info)

return jsonify({'result': '\n'.join(results)})
```